# How to remove the border of native-base tabs

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I need to remove the border as I marked in the image.

[image]

I am using react-native & native-base tabs. I need to remove the bottom border of tabs.

```
<Tabs>
      <Tab heading="Tab1">
        <Tab1 />
      </Tab>
      <Tab heading="Tab2">
        <Tab2 />
      </Tab>
      <Tab heading="Tab3">
        <Tab3 />
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution,

Need to implement **ScrollableTab**, Then

```
<ScrollableTab style={{ borderWidth: 0}}>
```

Answer (score 8):

For everyone still trying to remove the border. This is the problem due to elevation.
Add this to Tabs Tag:

```
<Tabs tabContainerStyle={{elevation: 0}}>
...
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Works for Android. For iOS use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57301488/2147383

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way:

```js
<Tabs tabContainerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<ScrollableTab style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, backgroundColor: 'some_color'}} 
/>
```

or

```
<TabHeading style={{
                backgroundColor: 'some_color',
                borderBottomWidth: 0,
}}>
```

or add below prop/attribute to  component:

```
tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: '#eff2f8'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I added a `borderWidth: 0px` to the styling and this worked for me,

Good Luck!