# native base Tabs - any idea how to remove the border around the tabs?

Tags: native-base

The following screenshot is the result of the code that is provided below. Any idea how the border around the tabs can be removed?

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Title, Text, Tabs, Tab } from 'native-base';

export default class Settings extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Container
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 30 }}>
          <Header hasTabs transparent>
              <Title style={{ color: 'grey' }}>
                Settings
              </Title>
          </Header>

          <Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 1 }}>
            <Tab heading="Tab1"
              tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              textStyle={{ color: 'grey' }}
              activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              activeTextStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}>
              <Text>TODO: Tab1</Text>
            </Tab>

            <Tab heading="Tab2"
              tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              textStyle={{ color: 'grey' }}
              activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              activeTextStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}>
              <Text>TODO: Tab2</Text>
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>

        </Container>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can´t be done with the default tabs component, there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466904/how-to-remove-the-border-of-native-base-tabs) using scrollable tabs, and if you want to do it modifying the source code , there's this [workaround](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/736) also

Answer (score 4):

Adding `tabContainerStyle={{ elevation: 0 }}` to the `<Tabs>` solves this issue.
It seems to be Elevation (shadows) and not Border